# FEST: Retrieving a cell value when cell is under a JTable with CellRenderPane

Tags: java, swing, fixtures, tablecellrenderer, fest

I have code like this:

```
//(...)
JTableFixture myTreeTable = frame.table(matcher);
```

If I try to obtain JCellFixtures or values or contents, everything is null. I am only obtaining the number of rows or columns. JTable internally uses a CellRendererPanel which I guess I have to fetch. But how? JTable has no ContainerFixture to make `.panel()`. Is there any way to get the cell values in these circumstances? How it is usually done when there is a cell renderer panel?

This is the hierarchy for the FEST debugger:

```
gui.treetable.myTreeTable[name=null, rowCount=33, columnCount=2, enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
   javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you table has a custom cell renderer you can provide your your own cell reader. Check out [Custom Cell Renderers](http://fest.codehaus.org/Custom+Cell+Renderers) article. It demonstrates how to extend `BasicJTableCellReader` and how to use the reader in `JTableFixture`.

Comment: Oops, I already found it but its exactly what I ended up doing!! For those who can have a similar need: I needed to cast inoming Component in valueAt for my custom BasicJTableCellReader to a JTree, but FEST does not tell the type, it says CellRendererPane. Then its only a matter of adding this cellreder to the table trough celReader(reader) method in JTableFixture.